# Log4net RollingFileAppender missing entries logged from Web API async method

Tags: asp.net, .net, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, log4net

I'm finding that entries logged from an async Web API 2 method are not being logged by the RollingFileAppender, however they are being logged AdoNetAppender.

My log4net configuration is as follows:-

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
        <param name="File" value="Log\\MyLog.log" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="500" />
        <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="100KB" />
        <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size" />
        <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %property{Url} %-5p %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
        <bufferSize value="1" />
        <threshold value="INFO" />
        <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <commandText value="INSERT INTO tblErrorLog ([EventDate],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
        <usetransactions value="false" />
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@log_date" />
            <dbType value="DateTime" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@thread" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="255" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@log_level" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="50" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%level" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@logger" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="255" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@message" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="4000" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%message" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@exception" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="2000" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%exception" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default priority -->
        <priority value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Whats the fix for this?

Comment: Do you mean _some_ entries are missing, or it doesn't log to the file at all?

Comment: I mean some, entries are logged to the file, however it is missing entries which are logged by the AdoNetAppender